# WebView2 - which DLL file have I to export to test on another machine in order to test my application?

Tags: c++, win32gui, webview2

I've a WIN32 application with a '.exe' where I use the webView2 library with its different object (CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOption, get_corewebview2,...).

I use also the "ImplementationLibrary" library in the application.

I would like to test my application on another computer (with Windows 10 and system 64 bits) by copying all necessary dll's. Which is the dll's necessary to test my application on another computer for WebView2 and ImplementationLibrary ? In which directory of my computer have I to take the dll library or other files ?

Answer (score 2):

For a Win32 C++ app, in addition to whatever files are required by your application directly, WebView2 requires you also ship the WebView2Loader.dll. You should be able to find it in your build folder along side your app executable. See the [Files to ship with the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#files-to-ship-with-the-app) document.

Additionally you'll need to install the WebView2 Runtime on the target machine. You can either install a non-stable channel version of the Edge browser or [Install the WebView2 Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#deploying-the-evergreen-webview2-runtime).